# ¿Como enviar mis datos de formulario con PDO?

Tags: javascript, php, pdo

El problema que tengo es que no inserta los datos de un formulario en la base de datos y no lanza ningún error

```
public function Save(){
    $link = new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->ServerDB.";dbname=".$this->DataBaseDB, $this->UserDB, $this->PassDB); //el connect lo hago por PDO
    $statement = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO payment (total,date_created,description,name,number_card,email,order_id)
        VALUES (:total, now(), :description,:name,:number_card,:email,:order_id)"); //query a ejecutar
    $statement->execute([ //ejecuta el query
        'total' => $this->total,
        'description' => $this->description,
        'name' => utf8_decode($this->name),
        'number_card'=> substr($this->card,strlen($this->card)-5,4),
        'email'=>$this->email,
        'order_id'=>$this->order->id
    ]);
    $this->order_number = $link->lastInsertId();  //obtengo el ultimo dato como referencia para mi
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al intentar probar los errores que me arrojaba mi función descubrí que mi error fue de sintaxis con el nombre de las variables y si puedo recomendar algo es, siempre revisar como están declaradas las variables.

```
  public function Save(){
      $dsn = "mysql:host=$this->ServerDB;dbname=$this->DataBaseDB";
      $link = new PDO($dsn, $this->UserDB, $this->PassDB);
      $this->date_created = date('Y-m-d');
      $statement = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO payment (total,date_created,description,name,number_card,email,order_id)
          VALUES (:total, :date_created, :description,:name,:number_card,:email,:order_id)");

      $statement->execute([
          'total' => $this->total,
          'date_created'=>$this->date_created,
          'description' => $this->description,
          'name' => utf8_decode($this->name),
          'number_card'=> substr($this->card,strlen($this->card)-5,4),
          'email'=>$this->email,
          'order_id'=>$this->order->id
      ]);
      
      $this->order_number = $link->lastInsertId();
      $lastInsertId = $link->lastInsertId();
      if($lastInsertId>0){ //este if puede ayudar a saber que tipo de error esta arrojando y saber que variable tienen mal declarada en caso de que no arroje ningún error o envié algo
      echo "<div class='content alert alert-primary' > Guay </div>";
      }
      else{
        echo "No se pueden agregar datos, comuníquese con el ";
      print_r($statement->errorInfo()); 
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

La verdad no veo ningun error pero si no los inserta es porque hay un error, parece que tu instalacion de php tiene desabilidado la configuracion de mostrar errores.

para poder ver los errores pon lo siguiente en tu script (al inicio en el index o donde quiera que inicie tu aplicacion).  o simplemente puedes revisar el error.log de tu servidor.

```
 ini_set('display_errors','stderr');

 ini_set('error_reporting',E_ALL);
```

Ojo: no debes hacer esto si estas en mode de produccion, solo en modo de  desarrollo.

Ademas deberias poner el siguiente atributo debajo de tu coneccion.

```
 $link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

se veria algo asi

```
 //es recomendable separar el dsn para que tu coneccion sea mas legible
 $dsn = "mysql:host=$this->ServerDB;dbname=$this->DataBaseDB";
 $links = new PDO($dsn, $this->UserDB, $this->PassDB);
 $link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

con esto podras ver que esta ocurriendo, donde esta el error

Comment: Me pone este error sabes a que se refiere?
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'description' in 'field list' in C:\xampp\htdocs\pruebas-aldhair\pagocurso\business\Payment.php:60
Stack trace:

Comment: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\pruebas-aldhair\pagocurso\business\Payment.php(60): PDOStatement-&gt;execute(Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\pruebas-aldhair\pagocurso\business\Payment.php(37): Payment-&gt;Save()
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\pruebas-aldhair\pagocurso\pay.php(6): Payment-&gt;Pay()
#3 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\pruebas-aldhair\pagocurso\business\Payment.php</b> on line <b>60</b><br />